# Is there a plugin that will add my name and date to the top of my files as a comment for Atom?

Tags: ide, atom-editor

Most of the work I do is for school which means I need to have my name, the date, the name of the assignment, and other stuff in a comment at the top of each file I edit. Does Atom have any good plug-ins for this?

Answer (score 0):

The following seem to be close to what you're looking for. You can customize the inserted templates:

- https://atom.io/packages/auto-copyright
- https://atom.io/packages/auto-header

Not sure whether they provide all of the fields you're looking for, but they look like a good starting point.